# android ndk-build undefined reference, but NM says it's there

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ld, nm

EDITED: solution at the end of the post.

I am building a shared library for android using NDK r8d, using the sample project hello-jni from the NDK, and some static libraries compiled with the ARM standalone toolchain.

NDK-BUILD complains about undefined reference. See the linker command and its output:

```
c:/android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-
androideabi-g++ -Wl,-soname,libhello-jni.so -shared --sysroot=c:/android/ndk/platforms
/android-9/arch-arm ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o ./obj/local
/armeabi/libDataProvider.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libPDF.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libMisc.a
 ./obj/local/armeabi/libNetwork.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libboost_filesystem.a ./obj/local
/armeabi/libcryptoeng.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libcryptopp.a ./obj/local/armeabi
/libMiniSstructs.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libOBSstructs.a ./obj/local/armeabi
/libSerialization.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libstdc++.a ./obj/local/armeabi
/libboost_iostreams.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libboost_thread.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libz.a 
./obj/local/armeabi/libboost_system.a -no-canonical-prefixes -Wl,--no-undefined 
-Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/armeabi/libhello-jni.so


c:/android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc
/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local
/armeabi/libNetwork.a(CertificatesManager.o): in function 
OBInfo::GetVersionAsNumber():c:\trunk\src\libMisc/obinfo.h:19: error: 
undefined reference to 'OBInfo::versionAsNumber'collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, NM says the symbol is actually there:

```
$ nm Tests/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/libMisc.a --demangle | grep versionAsNumber
00000000 D OBInfo::versionAsNumber
```

Simplified OBInfo.h:

```
class OBInfo
{
 public:    
    static uint32_t GetVersionAsNumber() {return versionAsNumber;};
 private:
    static uint32_t versionAsNumber;
};
```

Simplified OBInfo.cpp

```
#include "obinfo.h"
#include "version_info.h"
uint32_t OBInfo::versionAsNumber = VERSION_AS_NUMBER;
```

If I remove -Wl,--no-undefined the linker ends with no errors. Why LD doesn't find the symbol, but NM does?  (BTW: NM comes from MSYS, while LD comes from the toolchain)

EDIT: I solved the problem changing the order of static libraries in Android.mk LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES variable. I also recompiled some of the prebuilt libraries, because some were compiled with no optimization -O0 while others were -O2 optimized.

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: I have an exact problem, but in my case, I am linking only one .so lib. Remov -Wl, --no-undefined definitely make the code compile, but I don't get it why it didn't work?